# Mapbox Android basics: import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R

Tags: java, mapbox

I am trying to rebuild the example code of the Mapbox first steps tutorial for Android Studio (https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-android-sdk/). But I am struggeling with an import statement called

```
import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;
```

I get an error message in Andriod Studio: "Cannot resolve symbol 'mapboxandroiddemo'. I thought I would have to change that to my project name, but still getting the same error.

Whats wrong with this import statment and how to correct it?

Comment: Is this issue solved?  Apparently it's this demo you are trying https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/styles/BasicSymbolLayerActivity.java